# String.Replace on null values

Tags: c#

I have a Replace method which can accept Xml node names as variables, the Replace will be evaluated on 
each row in the Xml getting the value of the node before it evaluates the expression. Therefore if some
nodes don't exist the Replace will be evaluating on a null.

Given this condition is the following code is justified?

```
<chocolates>
    <chocolate>
        <name>Mars Bar</name>
    </chocolate>
    <chocolate>
        <name>Bounty</name>
        <type>Coconut</type>
    </chocolate>
</chocolates>

Replace(type, 'C', 'c')

public string Replace(string a, string b, string c) 
{
    if (a == null) return null;
    if (b == null || c == null) return a;

    return a.Replace(b, c); 
}
```

Comment: If you gave the parameters better names it'd be easier to see what's going on

Answer (score 2):

The code can be *simplified*:

```
// When designing public methods you'd rather give to the parameters more
// descriptive names than "a", "b", "c", e.g.
// "source", "toFind", "toReplace"
public string Replace(string a, string b, string c) 
{
    if ((a == null) || (b == null) || (c == null))
      return a;

    return a.Replace(b, c); 
}
```

Or even further with a help of the *trenary* operator:

```
public string Replace(string a, string b, string c) 
{
    return ((a == null) || (b == null) || (c == null)) ? a : a.Replace(b, c);
}
```

You should use `String`, e.g. `"c"`, `"C"` not `Char` `'C'`, `'c'` on call:

```
// All three arguments should be strings
String type = ...
...
Replace(type, "C", "c");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should call your function by :

```
Replace(type,"C","C");
```

(ofcourse "type" also needs to be a string value)

or try this to compare string to null :

```
if(a.Equals(null)) return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

An extension method would look neater I think

```
    public static class MyTestClass
    {
      public static string MyReplace(this string stringToSearch, string find, string replaceWith)
      {
        if(stringToSearch == null) return null;
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(find) || replaceWith == null) return stringToSearch;
        return stringToSearch.Replace(find, replaceWith);
      }
    }
```

Then you could just call

```
      type.MyReplace('C','c');
```

Edit:
Added the full code for an extension class, and added isNullOrEmpty instead of just a null check for "find" as you don't wanna pass an empty string to the Replace call

Answer (score 0):

You need also to check that b is not empty. Otherwise argument exception will occure

```
Console.WriteLine(Replace("dsfa", "", ""));
// Define other methods and classes here
public string Replace(string a, string b, string c) 
{
    if (a == null) return null; 
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(b) || c == null) return a;

    return a.Replace(b, c); 
}
```